# ClassCastException when replacing static host page with JSP in GWT project

Tags: java, jsp, gwt, locale

I'd like to use a JSP host page for my GWT project to auto-detect the locale as suggested in post [How to get the Current Locale in GWT using LocaleInfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10106973/how-to-get-the-current-locale-in-gwt-using-localeinfo) with

```
<meta name="gwt:property" content="locale=<%=request.getLocale()%>">
```

However, when I attempt to run the app in superdev mode even *without* adding this tag, I get 500 Server Error with the following stack trace:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl cannot be cast to javax.el.ExpressionFactory
    at javax.el.ExpressionFactory.newInstance(ExpressionFactory.java:198)
    at javax.el.ExpressionFactory.newInstance(ExpressionFactory.java:117)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.PageInfo.<init>(PageInfo.java:79)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:110)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:373)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.
compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:686)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:428)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:949)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1011)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

The JSP is:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">      
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="play.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="play/play.nocache.js"></script>
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried to add the javax.el-api jar to my build path, but the problem remains. A Google search of this class casting exception doesn't bring up anything relevant.

Comment: I would suspect that you have java-el libraries in your deployment clashing with the already existing libraries in jetty.
Can you add all the libraries you include in your deployment. ("mvn dependency:tree" should display them if you use maven)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my GWT project was referencing a java project which had the Tomcat library in its build path.  This was apparently creating conflicts with jetty in gwt super dev mode.  When I removed the library the conflict was resolved.